# How to implement a graphical 3-Way "Switch"

Tags: c#, winforms, button, switch-statement, toggle

I'm trying to build a 3-Way "Switch" in my WinForms project.

It only sends one command for all three "settings", but should alternate between 3 different background images each time the user clicks on the button. I've already implemented a 2-Way toggle switch into my project by using a `CheckBox` with it's appearance set to "Button", but I don't believe this method will work for a 3-Way switch.

Here is the code that I've tried, but it doesn't seem to do anything when the button is clicked:

```
    private void ThreeWayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage.Equals(Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_1))
        {
            ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_2;
        }
        else if (ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage.Equals(Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_2))
        {
            ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_3;
        }
        else if (ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage.Equals(Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_3))
        {
            ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_1;
        }
    }
```

Another method I tried is using a switch:

```
static int switch_state = 0;

//...

    protected void ThreeWayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch_state++;
        switch (switch_state)
        {
            case 1:
                ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_2;
                break;
            case 2:
                ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_3;
                break;
            case 3:
                ThreeWayButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ThreeWay_1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

This method *kind of* works; it cycles through the three images, but once it gets to the last one, it doesn't cycle through the images again.

If the second method is the appropriate one to use, I'd like it to revert back to `case 1` after the user clicks on the button when the `switch_state` is `case 3`

It should cycle between the three images each time the user clicks the button, no matter how many times the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is the good one, you just need to add:

```
if(switch_state > 3)
    switch_state = 1;
```

Just after your switch_state++, else it will continue incrementing thus doing nothing.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the extremely fast response!